# Flex doesn't help to make div responsive and I cannot understand the reason why?

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to make responsive layout of web page but stuck at the point when I want to make div (header) to be responsive. Even though I settled display: flex to all of the parent containers it still doesn't work properly.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 90rem;
  gap: 22rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  width: fit-content;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2rem;
}

.menu button:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding: 0 0;
}

#features {
  display: flex;
  width: 5.125rem;
  align-items: center;
}

#features>img {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu li>ul>li:hover>button {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.navbar>ul>li>.label {
  border: solid 1px #131313;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.navbar>ul>li>.label:hover {
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 className="header-logo">Logo Here</h1>
  <nav className="navbar">
    <ul className="menu">
      <li>
        <button>Home</button>
      </li>
      <li id="features">
        <button onClick={(e)=> someAction}>
              Features <img src={dropdownImg} alt="dropdown"></img>
            </button>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <button>Dropdown</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button>Dropdown</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button>Dropdown</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>Blog</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>Shop</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>About</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>Contact</button>
      </li>

      <li>
        <button className="label">
              <img src={profileImg} alt="profile"></img>
            </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button className="label">
              <img src={basketImg} alt="basket"></img>
            </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

And that's how it looks like. As you see the Logo's gone somewhere, I've got a scroll bar. And I cannot understand what is an issue.

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Your nav is styled to be all on one line and is longer than the page and you have a gap of 22rem in your header (I'm guessing that's the big space before the nav)

Comment: @Pete How would you suggest to fix that? I mean I need gap there but how to make it more responsive?

Comment: Why not use media queries to remove the gap on smaller screens or even turn it into a mobile burger menu when the nav doesn't fit - that's what most sites will do